# Is it possible for a MoveIteratorFactory to generate moves based on a current working solution?

Tags: optaplanner

I would like to create a kind of a "smart" MoveIteratorFactory for my VRP (time windowed) example based app. This move factory should return an Iterator that would generate each time a CompositeMove based on the current solution state.

Is it possible for the MoveIteratorFactory to create an Iterator that generates moves based on current solution state?

AFAIK MoveIteratorFactory's methods accept a ScoreDirector object, and it seems that the returned Iterator should generate moves using instances retrieved from the ScoreDirector's working solution. But are these instances being updated while the solver process is undergoing? Do they have all planning variables set according to the current working solution state, when **hasNext** and **next** methods are called? Or should an iterator have a field with a ScoreDirector instance, and generate moves using instances retrieved each time from the ScoreDirector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just make sure sure that the `cacheType` isn't `PHASE` or higher (by default it's fine because by default it's `JUST_IN_TIME`). See docs chapter 7.

At the beginning of every step it will call `createRandomMoveIterator()`, which can take into account the state of the current `workingSolution`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm only wondering what is the impact (performance) of allocating every time a fresh instance of iterator for each step?

Comment: neglectable, if it does create all moves in a list (otherwise you might as well use MoveListFactory)